# Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4311

Tags: 11.04, wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Broadcom BCM4311 Wireless not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38327/broadcom-bcm4311-wireless-not-working)

I have an HP Pavilion dv6000 laptop. The wifi worked perfectly when I had 10.10 installed, the system says that the driver is installed and activated but I can't get the wifi to connect or turn on. It was all pretty much "automatic" when I was running 10.10.

> 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)