# Kubuntu 11.04 wireless scan doesn't find network

Tags: wireless, broadcom

When I scan for networks in the network manager I do not find any. I have a broadcom wireless card.
My light on my laptop isn't blue and blue is the color when it is on (Yes I have the switch in the on position).
Running sudo ifconfig wlan0 up I get "SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory"
ifconfig -a returns (I removed some of the MAC) "

```
wlan0 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:a5:ad:**:**  
      BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

"
So the driver I'm assuming is there is a driver and rfkill is the following

```
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

In the Network Interfaces GUI it does not list the wlan0 though. Anyone have a clue as to what is going on. I've looked around and can't find much on this issue. I have other wireless devices finding and connecting to the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem with broadcom on my hp mini. this [[Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4311](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38279/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4311][1])

[1]: [Wireless doesn't work on a Broadcom BCM4311](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38279/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4311) brings me to other posts/threads and finally I solved the problem with broadcom. Sorry, I'm not a home to have a look on my hp mini to give you further information but maybe this evening when I#m at home.

Comment: Ok well let me know when you find out what you did

Comment: Did you ever remember how you did this?

Comment: The problem was BCM4311 and the STA driver for my wireless card.  I installed the firmware for b43. See here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10527475&postcount=5